# How to wait on WaitHandle without message pumping?

Tags: .net, multithreading, com

I want to call `WaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan)` in .NET, but I'm on the STA thread and it pumps messages while waiting.  For reasons that are beyond the scope of this question, I need to wait *without* pumping.  How can I wait for a WaitHandle to be signaled without pumping messages?

It seems in some scenarios that `WaitHandle.WaitOne` does not pump messages.  But it does sometimes for some messages.  See these links for more information on that:

1. [Managed and Unmanaged Threading in Microsoft Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74169f59.aspx)
2. [Managed blocking](http://blogs.msdn.com/cbrumme/archive/2003/04/17/51361.aspx)

Comment: I know the question has already been answered, but can you give a recipe that demonstrates that WaitHandle.WaitOne pumps messages? I don't really understand what's going on here and I'm curious.

Comment: wcoenen: I've added links in my question that indicate that WaitOne sometimes pumps messages.

Comment: The **Managed blocking** post is now at Chris Brumme's [personal site](https://cbrumme.dev/managed-blocking).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WaitForSingleObject or WaitForMultipleObjects are non-pumping waits; use p/invoke.

```
[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true)]
public static extern Int32 WaitForSingleObject(SafeWaitHandle handle, Int32 milliseconds);
```

-Oisin

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't know you could pass a SafeWaitHandle directly into a P/Invoke method.  That's cool.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Yeah, the .NET marshaller "knows" about types that expose an IntPtr (GetDangerousHandle in this case, iirc), so you can just replace that parameter in the signature and let the magic happen ;-)

Comment: For some reason, the limited pumping done by WaitOne() prevents minimized forms from being restored when calling WaitOne() in Form.OnActivated. Took me 2 hours to track that bug down to the WaitOne() call, but thanks to your answer here I could fix it quickly :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Apparently this was a [change introduced in Microsoft Vista](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yvesdolc/archive/2009/08/06/do-you-receive-wm-paint-when-waiting-for-a-com-call-to-return.aspx):  `CoWaitForMultipleHandles` now dispatches `WM_PAINT` messages.

[Vista bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/330906/vista-bug-iterating-a-com-collection-with-foreach-causes-your-thread-to-be-reentered-during-the-iteration-via-a-message-pump-this-happens-with-free-threaded-com-objects-that-do-not-cross-apartments).

A workaround is to use Microsoft's Application Compatibility Toolkit to set the DisableNewWMPAINTDispatchInOLE flag for your application.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a WPF app where the Dispatcher is the one running the message pumps during managed waits, the simplest way to disable the message pump during your wait is via [Dispatcher.DisableProcessing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.disableprocessing.aspx):

```
// The Dispose() method is called at the end of the using statement. 
// Calling Dispose on the DispatcherProcessingDisabled structure,  
// which is returned from the call to DisableProcessing, will 
// re-enable Dispatcher processing. 
using (Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.DisableProcessing())
{
    // Do work while the dispatcher processing is disabled.
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```