# What is the purpose of asynchronously connecting if the thread is still waiting?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I ran into the following code:

```
public ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

public void connectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    allDone.Set();
    Socket s = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    s.EndConnect(ar);
}

public int connect()
{
  try
  {
    var address = Dns.GetHostEntry(host).AddressList[0];
    var remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(address, port);
    var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    socket.BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(connectCallback), socket);
    allDone.WaitOne(15000);

    return true;
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
    return false;
  }  
}
```

It looks like it calls `BeginConnect` with a callback method.  Then the code waits on a ManualResetEvent to fire, which is set in the callback method.

Wouldn't it be just simpler to connect synchronously since the code is waiting regardless (15 second timeout nonewithstanding):

```
public int connect()
{
  try
  {
    var address = Dns.GetHostEntry(host).AddressList[0];
    var remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(address, port);
    var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    socket.Connect(remoteEP);

    return true;
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
    return false;
  }  
}
```

Comment: If enabling a timeout isn't reason enough, it might be that WaitOne keeps pumping messages on an STA thread. I'm not 100% sure that it does this, that's what [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896233/how-to-wait-on-waithandle-without-message-pumping) indicates.

Comment: @MikeZboray The timeout for socket.Connect is already 15 seconds.

Comment: Well, that still leaves my guess that it's about having an active message pump. Is this in a UI or an application with some STA COM objects?

Comment: @MikeZboray It's a .NET Core web app which had some coded copied and pasted from an older .NET 4.x project.

Answer (score 3):

In this instance yes you are technically correct. Patterns like this have a habit of creeping into code bases, usually because we want to take advantage of asynchronous patterns as a standard approach but sometimes we run into conflicting existing synchronous Boolean response code contracts.

However the async callback pattern is still valid because you have constrained the callback processing to a single function that could be reused from multiple connect processes, we can't see the rest of the class structure but this pattern would easily allow multiple overloads of `Connect` to exist. Perhaps there is already a fully asynchronous overload for `Connect`...

As this is a clear junction between **synchronous** and **asynchronous** paradigms, I would encourage developers to include comments that detail the reason why the wait is occurring, and why it should or shouldn't be refactored in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the async (APM) call and the ManualResetEvent  cancel each other out more or less.

Make sure you know about the [TaskFactory.FromAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_TaskFactory_FromAsync_System_Func_System_AsyncCallback_System_Object_System_IAsyncResult__System_Action_System_IAsyncResult__System_Object_System_Threading_Tasks_TaskCreationOptions_) for making it a Task based async Connect method.